# Convergence/divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\sqrt{n}}$$
Determine whether this series is convergent or not, with explanation.

Each element is positive, so I've tried bounding it by another convergent series, but couldn't see how.

I couldn't apply integral test, because I couldn't integrate it.

I'm struggling to figure out which convergence/divergence test I should use.
(I can use absolute convergence theorems too)

I would really appreciate some help!

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $\forall n>4$, $n^{\sqrt{n}}>n^2$.

Comment: Comparing with $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ is often one of the simplest ways.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28n^sqrt%28n%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity) and see whether it answers your questions

Comment: how would that help martigan, because according to the theorem in my course (maybe I'm just confused), we would need $$n^\sqrt{n}<n^2$$

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven Well, you have the inverse of $n^{\sqrt{n}}$...

Comment: oh right it all makes sense now! thank you!

Comment: struggling with what test to use? what test did you use with what result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $n^2<n^\sqrt{n}$ for $n>4$. Then compare your series with the one given by the general term $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$1\lt \sqrt2\lt\sqrt{n}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\ge3\implies0\lt\dfrac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\lt\dfrac{1}{n^{\sqrt2}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\ge3$